# .Net Core Hangfire RecurringJob Start Time

Tags: .net-core, hangfire

How can I customize recurring job start time. I can make it to run every 15 munites. When it will run for the first time I want it to start at 21:00 and run every 15 minutes.
Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: you mean you want to start at 0th min of full hour and then after every 15 min.

Comment: as far as i know it is not possible to with one job. what you have to do is to create a one job BackgroundJob.Schedule() exact time you want to start and then then inside that job you create one recurring job which get's executes at every 15 min. keep in mind about the delay and time sync also.